# Problem with latex math expression

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I've been trying to write `p = sqrt2^(sqrt2)` like this `$p= \sqrt 2^ (\sqrt2)$`. And, the output I am getting is not what I am looking for. How can I write this properly?

Comment: Try `$p= \sqrt{2}^{(\sqrt{2})}$`. Note that since the exponent is complex it must be placed in braces. Do you need the parenthesis?

Comment: Thanks. It worked now. And, thanks for editing. I meant to say output not input.

Comment: The expression worked the way I wanted without the parenthesis. But, I think I can still add it though. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @azetina an answer? or too localized? you decide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis in the example provided is not really necessary. The problem here was the fact of forgetting to group the superscripts/subscripts in braces. This is a good practice. Hence the right approach is illustrated below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
$p= \sqrt{2}^{(\sqrt{2})}$

$p= \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$
\end{document}
```